# creating a simple login page

Tags: javascript, mysql

I've been doing software dev for a number of yrs but new to web programming.  I'd like to create a simple login page for my website.  I've done extensive research but can't find anything I can just cut and paste.  How can I get something up and running very quickly?

Comment: Kind of vague--What server side language are you using?

Comment: Your going to need something server side, not just JS.

Comment: What server-side language are you using?

Comment: What technologies are you using? What have you tried? Are you just looking for someone to do your work for you? Are you using a framework?

Comment: "I can't find anything I can just cut and paste"....sigh....

Comment: developing is not just cut and paste

Answer (score 1):

Use something like [Apache Basic Auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). It's not a login page, but it's the closest thing you can get to a login with just cut and paste.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using php and MySql, there's a good one to start with on tutorialzine. Just download the source and upload it to your site. It's built on a small tutorial, so if your new to web programming I really would recommend to read it trough. It's a small step by step tutorial where only the most important parts are described...

http://tutorialzine.com/2009/10/cool-login-system-php-jquery/